# What do kube_state metrics Return?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to write some rules for alerts in prometheus.
The rules I write seem to be syntactically correct and I know it satisfies, but I am not able to see it as an Alert.
For example-

```
 IF kube_pod_container_status_running{pod="pod-name",container="container_name"} > 0
```

Is this the right way to write it? What does kube_pod_container_status_running return? bool or some number?